# Open website via computer IP address while running tomcat locally with a router?

Tags: networking, router, portforwarding

I'm working on a website for a friend, developing using Eclipse/Tomcat. I'm running it locally and trying to open it via my internet port IP address, but I can't get it to work. The computer I am running it from is connected to a router, so it is running off of 192.168.1.4, and `http://192.168.1.4:8080/Mobile_Site/index.jsp` works. However when I try and open it via my internet port IP, `http://67.xxx.244.xx:8080/Mobile_Site/index.jsp` it doesn't find it from any device, even outside my local network. Is there a way to send the link when running locally when connected to a router?

Comment: What you mean by "my internet port IP"?

Comment: My routers wording uses "Internet Port" to describe my external IP address (the 67.xxx.244.xx one).  Sorry networking is not my strong suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure your router port forwarding (or virtual servers depending on the router) to forward TCP connections from `67.xxx.244.xx:NNNN` to `192.168.1.4:8080`.

Then you give the `67.xxx.244.xx:NNNN` address to your friend.

Note: `NNNN` at your router doesn't need to be `8080`, as long as the port forwarding is set properly.

Comment: Yep I had to forward port 4000 and/or 8080 (did both) for my 192.168.1.4 internal IP address.  Thanks!